# Solving Second-Order Non-Homogeneous Recurrence Relations

Tags: recurrence-relations, fibonacci-numbers, analysis-of-algorithms

**I'm trying to solve the following recurrence relation:**

$F(n) = F(n -1) + F(n -2) + Θ(n)$ for $n > 1$, and

$Θ(n) = c_1n + c_2$ , where $c_1, c_2 > 0$

and with two initial conditions $F(0) = 0$, $F(1) = 1$

**For the homogeneous version of the recurrence, I have:**

$F(n) - F(n - 1) - F(n - 2) = 0$

**Finding the roots, I get:**

$F(n) = α(\frac{1 + √5}{2})^n + β(\frac{1 - √5}{2})^n$

**If I take the initial conditions into consideration and incorporate the non-homogeneous part, I have:**

$F(0) = α(\frac{1 + √5}{2})^0 + β(\frac{1 - √5}{2})^0 - c_1(0) - c_2 = 0$

$α + β - c_2 = 0$

$α + β = c_2$

$β = c_2 - α$

$F(1) = α(\frac{1 + √5}{2})^1 + β(\frac{1 - √5}{2})^1 - c_1(1) - c_2 = 1$

$α(\frac{1 + √5}{2}) + β(\frac{1 - √5}{2}) - c_1 - c_2 = 1$

$α(\frac{1 + √5}{2}) + β(\frac{1 - √5}{2}) = 1 + c_1 + c_2$

Plugging in value of β from F(0) evaluation

$α(\frac{1 + √5}{2}) + (c_2 - α)(\frac{1 - √5}{2}) = 1 + c_1 + c_2$

$α(\frac{1 + √5}{2}) - α(\frac{1 - √5}{2}) + c_2(\frac{1 - √5}{2}) = 1 + c_1 + c_2$

$α√5 + c_2(\frac{1 - √5}{2}) = 1 + c_1 + c_2$

$α√5 = 1 + c_1 + c_2 - c_2(\frac{1 - √5}{2})$

$α = \frac{1 + c_1 + c_2 - c_2(\frac{1 - √5}{2})}{√5}$

**Now that I have the values of α and β, I can plug them into the formula:**

$F(n) = α(\frac{1 + √5}{2})^n + β(\frac{1 - √5}{2})^n - c_1n - c_2$

$F(n) = (\frac{1 + c_1 + c_2 - c_2(\frac{1 - √5}{2})}{√5})(\frac{1 + √5}{2})^n + (c_2 - α)(\frac{1 - √5}{2})^n - c_1n - c_2$

$F(n) = (\frac{1 + c_1 + c_2 - c_2(\frac{1 - √5}{2})}{√5})(\frac{1 + √5}{2})^n + (c_2 - \frac{1 + c_1 + c_2 - c_2(\frac{1 - √5}{2})}{√5}))(\frac{1 - √5}{2})^n - c_1n - c_2$

Now, this should be the solution to the recurrence relation, but, for example, when I use $c_1 = 2$ and $c_2 = 3$, I get the following values:

$F(2) = 2$  --> should be 8

$F(3) = 6$  --> should be 18

$F(4) = 13$ --> should be 37

$F(5) = 26$ --> should be 68

And so on ...

**Could anybody tell me where I'm going wrong? Thanks**

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format math on this site.  To begin with, enclose all math expressions (including numbers) in `$` signs.  For example, `$x_1^2$` will give you $x_1^2$.  You'll get a much better response if your posts are easy to read.

Comment: This is hard to read, but it looks to me that you are using $\alpha$ and $\beta$ when you are trying to find a particular solution.  You should first find a particular solution, and then determine the coefficients.

Comment: Ok. I fixed the format, so it should be a little easier to read. Is it not possible to find a generalized solution using $c_1$ and $c_2$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm following what you've done, you've found that the general solution to the associated homogenous equations is
$$\alpha\left(\frac{1+\sqrt5}2\right)^n+\beta\left(\frac{1-\sqrt5}2\right)^n$$  You have a typo when this formula first appears -- a plus sign instead of a minus sign in the second term.

That looks right.  (I haven't checked it, I'm going by memory here.)

The next thing you should do is to find any particular solution to the inhomogeneous equation $$F_n-F_{n-1}-F_{n-2}=c_1n+c_2$$
Because of the form of the right hand side, we guess that there will be a solution of the form $F_n=an+b$ for some constants $a$ and $b$.

Substituting in in the inhomogeneous equation, we get $$an+b-(a(n-1)+b)-(a(n-2)+b)=c_1n +c_2$$ which, if I haven't made a mistake, leads to $$a = -c_1,\ b=-(c_2+3c_1)$$

Now the general solution to the inhomogeneous equation is the general solution to the homogeneous equation plus any particular solution to the inhomogeneous equation:
$$F_n= \alpha\left(\frac{1+\sqrt5}2\right)^n+\beta\left(\frac{1-\sqrt5}2\right)^n-c_1n-c_2-3c_1$$

Now you can substitute the initial values $F_0=0,\ F_1=1$ and determine $\alpha and $\beta$.  Check my calculations before you do, though.

Comment: Did you simplify $an+b−(a(n−1)+b)−(a(n−2)+b)=c1n+c2$ by using $n=0$?

Comment: @user10605996 No.  I expanded the left-hand side, and equated the coefficients.  You could do it by substituting in a couple of values of $n$, though.  It's a linear relation in $n$ so two points will determine the coefficients.

Comment: Ok. I just wasn't sure how you got $a$ and $b$ because I'm getting $a=\frac{nc_1+c_2+b}{-n+3}$ and $b=-nc_1-c_2-na+3a$

Comment: @user10605996 $a$ and $b$ are constants; they don't depend on $n$.  I ended up with $$c_1n+c_2=-an+3a-b$$  This has to be true for every integer $n$, and the only way that can happen is if we have the same polynomial on both sides of the equation.

Comment: Ok. That makes sense. Since you have $c_1n+c_2=−an+3a−b$, shouldn't we add $−c_1n−c_2+3c_1$ to the formula instead of $−c_1n−c_2-3c_1$

Comment: @user10605996 The particular solution is $an+b$.  We have to figure out what $a$ and $b$ are, and then add $an+b$ to the general solution of the homogeneous equation.